trying to install Grafana via helm error namespaces not found
I am attempting to install grafana via helm 8.4.1 
I install with helm install my-grafana . --namespace my-monitoring
I receive an error:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: 2 errors occurred:
* namespaces "grafana" not found
* namespaces "grafana" not found
in the values file I have not specified any namespace
everything works just fine if I use helm install my-grafana . --namespace grafana

The error occurs because the chart might reference the grafana namespace in values.yaml or templates. You can fix this by checking and removing any hardcoded grafana namespace references in the Helm chart.
You should then add the --create-namespace flag if my-monitoring doesn't exist:
helm install my-grafana . --namespace my-monitoring --create-namespace


I put a configmap for each dashboard in the templates folder.
Those needed to have the same namespace as the grafana:
I changed the namespace from grafana to my-monitoring and it's now working.
